# Read data from a list( Container ) and store it in file in selenium

Tags: java, arrays, selenium, xpath, ui-automation

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bvTVp.png)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RYZW5.png) I'm not able to store list value in the text file

Comment: You may want to read [ask].

Answer (score 0):

Solved with following code

```
    Util.webElementClickByXpath("//*[@id=\"selectOpGrp\"]/i");
    Thread.sleep(5000);
    List<WebElement> listElement = 
    driver.findElements(By.className("oplogotext"));
    for(int i =0;i<listElement.size();i++) {
     String elementText = listElement.get(i).getText(); 
     System.out.println(elementText);
```